# Hibernate: проверка грамматики

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Можно ли проверить через Hibernate грамматику конкретного SQL диалекта (Postgres, MySQL, Oracle и т.д.) без выполнения самого запроса? Хочется по строке запроса в случае некорректной грамматики получить примерное описание проблемы, например, что неверный тип данных.

Если нельзя, то как это примерно можно реализовать?

Comment: как вариант, использовать Antlr и грамматику нужного SQL-диалекта: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, к сожалению, нет полной грамматики ни для PL/SQL, ни для PG/SQL на Antlr. Получилось найти только официальную для Yacc. Но ее не сконвертировать, так как типы грамматик разные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно выполнения:

```
session.createQuery(hql);
```

При этом выполняется только компиляция запроса. Если что-то не так с запросом вывалится `Exception`, который уже можно диагностировать.

Comment: А для нативных запросов будет работать?

Comment: Нет, не будет. Для нативных запросов надо использовать `createSQLQuery()`